Streamlit Aggrid Autofit to container not working
Background
I previously had streamlit-aggrid 0.3.4.post3 installed and my code worked as expected. The columns would autosize to fit the table container.
Problem
I updated my library to streamlit-aggrid 1.0.5, and now it no longer works, When the table first loads, I catch a glimpse of the columns correctly fitting the container, but then streamlit refreshes immediately, and the table columns autofits to their contents, not to the container.
What I've tried
I've removed my custom_css, I've played around with the below two lines; commenting them out & trying different options (NO_AUTOSIZE, FIT_CONTENTS, FIT_CONTAINER, etc). but no luck.
gb.configure_default_column(autoSizeColumns=True, resizable=True)
columns_auto_size_mode=ColumnsAutoSizeMode.FIT_ALL_COLUMNS_TO_VIEW,

My guess is that there is nothing wrong with my code (given it works perfectly fine when I revert back to 0.3.4.post3). I suspect that in v1.0.5 there is another process somewhere that is overwriting the formatting.
Help requested
Anyone else experience this issue. anyone else find a way to resolve it?
code
# Format DF
df = format_column_headers(df)

# Unique Key
u_key = id + '_grid'

# Define Grid Options
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_selection('single', use_checkbox=True)
gb.configure_pagination(enabled=False)
# gb.configure_default_column(autoSizeColumns=True, resizable=True)
grid_options = gb.build()

# Apply a custom header class
for col_def in grid_options['columnDefs']:
    col_def['headerClass'] = 'custom-header'  # Apply a custom header class

grid_response = AgGrid(
    df,
    gridOptions=grid_options,
    height=min(600, (3 + len(df.index)) * 30),
    width='100%',
    enable_enterprise_modules=False,
    key=u_key,
    theme='streamlit',
    custom_css=get_aggrid_css(),
    columns_auto_size_mode=ColumnsAutoSizeMode.FIT_ALL_COLUMNS_TO_VIEW,
)

